# MissingResourceException for the vietnamese locale

Tags: java, properties, resourcebundle

I am trying to use `ResourceBundle` to read data from a ".properties" file but it cannot be loaded. I receive this error:

> `Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name language_Vi, locale vi`

##### Code which collects the properties

```
// Vietnamese login version
private static void VietnameseLogin() { 
    Locale locale = new Locale("Vi"); 
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("language", locale); 
    Login(bundle); 
}

// English login version
private static void EnglishLogin() {
    Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("language", locale);
    Login(bundle); 
}
```

##### Directory structure

[image: file structure]

Comment: Your code does not match the error message or it would say "...base name language, locale vi" not  "...base name language_Vi, locale vi"

Comment: i did change to language_Vi and language_En but still raise java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name language_Vi, locale vi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names of language should be lowercase and variants are uppercase - so be precise with name of the files: `language_en.properties` and `language_vi.properties`. It is a good idea to keep your preferred language file as the fallback so rename one of the above to just `language.properties` without the 2 digit iso country code.

The following code would search for resource bundle named "language" as class and properties definitions in the top level of every classpath jar and directory:

```
// DEPRECATED IN JDK19, use Locale.of("vi")
Locale locale = new Locale("Vi"); 

ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("language",locale);
```

=> SEARCHES FOR:

```
Class language.class
resource language.properties
Class language_vi.class
resource language_vi.properties
PLUS class+properties for lang and lang+variants of Locale.getDefault() eg language_en and language_en_GB
```

Resource pathnames should not contain `\\`.If you wish to use a directory to keep them, use `/`. So this would search under a sub-folder:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("mydir/name",locale);
```

=> SEARCHES FOR:

```
Class mydir/name.class
Resource mydir/name.properties
Class mydir/name_vi.class
Resource mydir/name_vi.properties
PLUS mydir/name class+properties for lang and lang+variants of Locale.getDefault() eg lmydir/name_en and mydir/name_en_GB
```

Comment: sorry i put the wrong code for the  question, so i did edit it as above. but it still raise MissingResourceException :((( that backslash before was to locate that Language folder.

Comment: @TranGiangAnh See edit, do not use backslash. If you use a sub-folder use `/` as separator.